# update deep nested array in redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I've been looking around to find a solution or a guide to cover my problem..
I need to find the right subsubdoc by an ID i'm passing with the action, and then the right subsubsubdoc by an ID that i'm also passing with the action.

I'm fetching the object from an API and then putting in the state.
The object I have simular to this:

```
proj = {
  id:"zf123ada123ad",
  name:"examp",
  subdoc:{
    name:"subdoc examp",
    subsubdoc:[{
               id:"zcgsdf123zaar21",
               subsubsubdoc:[{
                             id:"af2317bh123",
                             value: "heyhey"   //this value I want to update
                            }]
              }]
}
}
```

in my reducer i have something like this atm:
I know this don't work because I don't get the specific object in the array, but that's what i don't know how to do. I have the id of the subsubsubdoc that i want to change value of.

```
export function answerUpdate(state = [], action){
  switch(action.type){
    case 'ANSWER_UPDATE_FETCH_SUCCESS':
      return {
        ...state,
        proj: {
          ...state.proj,
          subdoc: {
            ...state.proj.subdoc,
            subsubdoc: {
                ...state.proj.subdoc.subsubdoc,
                subsubsubdoc: {
                    ...state.proj.subdoc.subsubdoc.subsubsubdoc,
                value: "hoy"
                }
            }
          }
        }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

What I would like is this but a working and acceptable code inside the reducer:

```
state.doc.subdoc.subsubdoc.where(x => x.id ==theInputId1)
   .subsubsubdoc.where(
   x => x.id == theInputId2).value = theInputValue
```

**Very grateful for every answer!!**

Comment: Same way as anything else if you don't have reasonable indices--you iterate.

Comment: Can you elaborate? :)

Comment: https://lodash.com/docs#set ?

Comment: You have a few issues to make this efficient. If `proj` was an array as well instead of an object and the keys in the subs are the same, so `subdoc` everywhere instead of subsubdoc` in level 2 etc, then you could do this recursively. But in cases where you need to reference a particulat doc often, just flatten the array into an object so you have direct access to any object, while keeping proj as the tree.

Comment: yeah but I don't know how to do it in a redux reducer and to return the correct thing an so on, it gets me confused.

Comment: @Shilly I should also probably mention, i get the the data from a fetch from the database that i then put into the state, and the reason i got arrays and different ID's is because i use each of the docs to different things but they are connected in the end as an object that i save into mongoDB

Answer (score 0):

Assuming action.payload is your Id, you should do something like

```
    case 'ANSWER_UPDATE_FETCH_SUCCESS': {
            const index = state.proj.subdoc.subsubdoc.findIndex(({id}) => id === action.payload);
            const updatedObject = {
               ...state.proj.subdoc.subsubdoc[index],
               value: newValue
            }

            return {
               ...state,
               proj: {
                 ...state.proj,
                 subdoc: {
                   ...state.proj.subdoc,
                   subsubdoc: [
                        ...state.proj.subdoc.subsubdoc.slice(0, index),
                        updatedObject,
                        ...state.proj.subdoc.subsubdoc.slice(index)
                      ]
                    }
                  }
            }
    }
```

you can have additional checks for when id is not present, simplify by reducing the usage of state.proj.subdoc.subsubdoc by storing it in a variable.

It is advised not to have such deep nesting in redux store.

Comment: Hmm this looks like something, the problem I have is, the payload contains three things, the id of subsubdoc, and the id of subsubsubdoc and also the value that subsubsubdoc should change to. So i first need to find the correct subsubdoc and then find the correct subsubsubdoc in there and then change it's value.

Also I don't know how to do it otherwise, since i'm gathering this data from an API to update and then passing it back to update the data in the database

Comment: well in that first find the subdoc, then update the subsubdoc and then subsubsubdoc. Please try to avoid so many levels of nesting. Make separate reducer for each, then combine them while updating in the api

Comment: How would that work? The API is sending me this object, how should i recieve it? Or should i change the code in the API?

Comment: can you create a codesandbox with the code and add it to the question so it would be much better to help out

Answer (score 0):

My first concern would be to get the data into a regular format. If you have no control over the API, try making the format yourself once you receive it. This will save you alot of complex code. Smart data structures and dumb program code usually performs better than louzy data structures and tons of complex code.

```js
var project = [
  { "id": "zf123ada123ad",
    "name": "examp",
    "value": null,
    "docs": [
      { "id": "zcgsdf123zaar21",
        "name": "examp-sub",
        "value": null,
        "docs": [
          { "id": "af2317bh123",
            "name": "examp-sub-sub",
            "value": "heyhey",
            "docs": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
 // 1st option: Recusively search.
var search = function( id ) {
  var search_level = function( result, next ) {
    if ( result ) return result;
    else {
      if ( next.id === id ) return next;
      else return next.docs.reduce( search_level, null );
    }
  };
  return search_level;
};
var heyhey_search = project.reduce( search( "af2317bh123" ), null );
console.log( 'option 1:' );
console.log( heyhey_search );
// 2nd option: Make a hash table. This is preferred if you need to access records by id often.
var flatten_hash = function( result, next ) {
  // Own.
  result[ next.id ] = next;
  // Nested docs.
  return next.docs.reduce( flatten_hash, result );
};
var project_hash = project.reduce( flatten_hash, {} );
var heyhey_hash = project_hash[ "af2317bh123" ];
console.log( 'option 2:' );
console.log( heyhey_hash );
```

```js
var state = [
 {
   "id": 1,
    "docs": [
     {
       "id": 3,
        "value": "old value"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
   "id": 2,
    "docs": []
  }
];
console.log( 'old state' );
console.log( JSON.stringify( state ) );
var object_3 = state[0].docs[0];
object_3.value = "new value";
console.log( 'new state' );
console.log( JSON.stringify( state ) );
```

Comment: the problem is the data isn't really that simple, each doc has different types of property that is unique to it, How would this work in a reducer?

Comment: The easiest way would then be to make a model for the properties of each type of doc. So that depending on the document type, you have an array of the correct properties. You could also detect inline which properties are on each document, but that will be alot of code. You should ask the database admin to change his database so there's a minimum of consistent property names and only the values are different since the current database structure complicates everything from backend to frontend without any visible advantages.

Comment: But since you control the API, can't you just create another service that will use the mongo search function to return the correct record instead of trying to loop it from out of the proj object?

Comment: It does return the correct object but the question i have is how do i update that object in the nested big object :P

Comment: Once you find the correct object in any way, just change the properties. If you didn't clone anything, the found object will be the same object as the one deep inside the nested arrays.

Comment: so how would that look like in the code in the reducer? Let's say i return the correct subsubsub doc from the api to that then get's sent to the reducer

Comment: I don't understand. You get the correct state. Then you search the correct object inside that state. You change the value of that object. Then return the new state. I don't work with redux myself so correct me if I'm wrong, but as far as I understood: get state, update state, return state.

Comment: The problem is i don't know how to access that object in my main object inside the reducer to edit it :P

Comment: What I would like is like,

state.doc.subdoc.subsubdoc.where(x => x.id == theInputId1).subsubsubdoc.where(x => x.id == theInputId2).value = theInputValue

inside the reducer, and I don't know how to do that inside there :P

Comment: I still don't understand: `var doc = state.doc.subdoc.subsubdoc.where(x => x.id == theInputId1).subsubsubdoc.where(x => x.id == theInputId2); doc.value = 'new value'; return state;`

Comment: yeah but what I want to do it update the current that so the current states subsubsub doc gets updated

Comment: And `var doc` above isn't the current states subsubsub doc?

Comment: yeah it is, but then i need to return that subsubsub doc into that current state

Comment: It's a reference. var doc should be the same object as the object inside the state. So changing anything on var doc should automatically change it inside the state as well, where its nested 3 levels deep. So you don't actually have to write back the update into the state after updating it. I'll post an example below.

Comment: I have updated my answer to include a second snippet that shows you what I mean. We have the initial state and log it to the console. Then we search the correct object inside the state. I just use an absolute path here for convenience. The we update the value of that object. If you then log the state again, you see that the value inside the state has changed, even if we extracted the object from the state to edit it. `var object_3` and the object inside the state are the same objects in memory. Google pass-by-reference and pass-by-value for more information.

Comment: Yeah something like that might work, but how would it look like if i only have the id to go on, and not the array placement?

Comment: Is there ANY way to know that level 1 the property is named 'subdoc', level 2 'subsubdoc' etc ? If so, you can create the correct name from the depth of the levels. `var prop = 'sub'.repeat(index) + 'doc'`. Or are they like random values? Are there more properties that contain arrays? If not, you can detect the property that is an array with `Array.isArray()`. If there isn't any way to know which the correct property is, you are stuck with creating another object containing the correct property names for each level and complaining to the boss about that database admin. ;)

Comment: If you are the database admin, just throw the database away and start over. Use consistent property names for everything and use the values of those properties to signify the differences between the docs instead of using the properties themselves.

Comment: A quick fix would be to add one consistent property to each doc. So like `"docs_property": "subdoc"` for the doc with id `zf123ada123ad`, `"docs_property": "subsubdoc"` for doc `zcgsdf123zaar21` etc. Then you can keep everything as is and just use the docs_property to select the correct property in each doc.